# display json result in table format from sqlite database file

Tags: javascript, json, html, sqlite

I want display data from mysqlite database file.This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <script src="sql.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>My App</h1>
<div id="res" style="width: 100%">
</div>
<script>
    function loadBinaryFile(path,success) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", path, true); 
        xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var data = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
            var arr = new Array();
            for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
            success(arr.join(""));
        };
        xhr.send();
    };


    loadBinaryFile('MyData.db', function(data){
        var db = new SQL.Database(data);

        var res = db.exec("SELECT * FROM MyRecord");
      // document.getElementById("demo").textContent = JSON.stringify(res);
        var data=JSON.stringify(res);
      document.getElementById("res").textContent=data;


});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the output in this format:

```
[{"columns":["id","name","gender","fname"],"values":[[1,"divya","female","rao"],[3,"nithin","male","kumar"]]}]
```

Now,How can I display this json data in a table format.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{"columns":["id","name","gender","fname"],"values":[[1,"divya","female","rao"],[3,"nithin","male","kumar"]]}];

data = data[0];


var html = '<table><tr>';

data.columns.forEach(d => {
 html += '<th>' + d + '</th>'
});

html += '<tr>';

data.values.forEach( row => {
 html += '<tr>';
 row.forEach( item => {
   html += '<td>'+ item +'</td>'
  });
  html += '</tr>';
});

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: When I add this code I got error like "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" and also  I have used   var db = new SQL.Database(data);  in my code.

Comment: I have used data as the variable name. you could rename it to jsonData. The code posted above converts the json format specified above into html table syntax.

Comment: sorry.I too used the same variable name i.e.var data=JSON.stringify(res); and am getting that error. If I hardcode json data as you specified am getting the output. and instead of that if I use JSON.stringify(res),getting the error

Comment: Dont stringify the response. Just use res instead of data in the snippet. It should work give that res is in the format `[{"columns":["id","name","gender","fname"],"values":[[1,"divya","female","rao"],[3,"nithin","male","kumar"]]}]`.